# summing same numbers of different lists into another list

Tags: python, list, function, sum, append

#Now I know there are easier methods, but I need to make it in a #function and this is my try. Now it isn't working, but could you pls #help me?

```
def intersection(l1, l2):
    l3 = []
    for x in range(0, len`length `(l1)):
        if x == l2:
            l3.append(x)
    return l3

print(intersection([2, 3, 4, 7, 1],[0, -1, 4, 5, 1]))
```

Comment: _Now it isn't working_ Be more specific.  Tell us what the program **actually does**, and explain how that is different from what you **wanted**.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate integers from 0 to `len(l1)` instead of the iterating list items. You should use

```
for x in l1:
```

instead of

```
for x in range(0, len`length `(l1)):
```

Also you have an error in comparing items. You should use:

```
if x in l2:
```

instead of

```
if x == l2:
```

Full code sample:

```
def intersection(l1, l2):
    l3 = []
    for x in l1:
        if x in l2:
            l3.append(x)
    return l3

print(intersection([2, 3, 4, 7, 1],[0, -1, 4, 5, 1]))
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The best / fastest way to do this is to use [`set.intersection`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/intersection.html):

```
def intersection(l1, l2):
     return set(l1).intersection(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's np.intersect1d method.

```
import numpy as np
def intersection(l1, l2):
    return np.intersect1d(l1,l2).tolist()
print(intersection([2, 3, 4, 7, 1],[0, -1, 4, 5, 1]))
```

Output :

```
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate both lists simultaneously, sum each pair and put it into new list.

```
def intersection(l1, l2):
    result = []
    for item1, item2 in zip(l1, l2):
        result.append(item1 + item2)
    return result

print(intersection([2, 3, 4, 7, 1],[0, -1, 4, 5, 1]))
```

Comment: @DarthVader63 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted and upvote it.